# Migrate SQL2005 Enterprise Reporting Services into SQL2005 Express

Tags: sql-server-2005

Currently I have Reporting Services install in SQL EE 2005. But reporting database is routing to another server.

My intention is uninstall SQL 2005 EE from current server and install SQL 2005 Express. Then routing back the reporting database.

I'm not sure whether the Reporting Services working fine after running in SQL 2005 Express.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work fine as SQL Express with Advanced Services includes reporting services.  Just backup the SSRS databases, then restore them back to SQL Express after you install it.